# Python socket.error: [Errno 61] Connection refused

Tags: python, sockets

I am very new to socket programming.  I am trying to connect to a power supply over ethernet.  My Mac (OS X) is connected to an ethernet switch and the power supply is also connected to the switch.  I have some code written in python to send/receive commands/messages to/from the power supply.

The switch interface allows me to assign a static IP to the supply.  It is this same IP that I use as the target IP in the following code:

```
    def __init__( self, IP_TARGET ):
        IP = IP_TARGET
        PORT = 8080
        self.supply = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM )
        self.supply.connect( (IP, PORT) )
```

This code runs without any issues.  My next goal is communicate with the device using the following code:

```
    def getDeviceInfo( self ):
        self.supply.send('some command ')
        self.supply.recv(10)
```

Using some print statements I have narrowed the issue down to the recv() command.  The send() throws no errors.  I get the following error

```
...in getDeviceInfo
self.supply.recv(10) socket.error: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

I am able to ping the device using the IP that I assigned it using the ethernet switch.  I have firewall off.  I have searched the www for clues as to how I might resolve this error, but to no avail.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you on TCP or UDP protocol?...try changing `socket.SOCK_DGRAM` to `socket.SOCK_STREAM` instead.

Comment: @Iron Fist     

As I understand UPD = `socket.SOCK_DGRAM` and TCP = `socket.SOCK_STREAM`.

I tried making the suggested change and got the following terminal error:

`getDeviceInfo
    self.supply.send('some command ')
socket.error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`

Comment: I can't exactly tell, until you let us know what are you running on the server side, your power supply in this case, is it an HTTP server or what?

Comment: @IronFist      
The supply is on a private network

Comment: What is this "power supply"? It might help to tell what it is so that people could identify its protocol

Comment: The supply is using a Digi connect ME ethernet port.  
Part number = DC-ME-01T-S

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there is nothing running on the host and port you specified (you can check it with nmap, for example).

In the case it does, is it expecting to receive anything and responding to it?

EDIT: your code is not working because in the remote host and the port you specified (8080), there must be some some code running, listening for messages and responding to them. If there is nothing running on that port, it obviously returns you the "Connection refused" error.

In other words, you created the client, but not the server :P

Comment: The supply shows up in switch's interface.  The port I chose was random (I thought anything above 4096 would be okay).  

I will have to learn about nmap before I use it.  But to answer the last question, I am not sure that its expecting to receive.  I was expecting that by sending it a command that I would simply get a response (clearly I am having wishful thoughts).

Comment: I edited my answer, I hope I explained myself better :D

Answer (score 0):

> The port I chose was random (I thought anything above 4096 would be
>   okay).

See the [Digi Connect® Family Command Reference](https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/DigiDocs/90000566/default.htm) on how to [Access the Command Line](https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/DigiDocs/90000566/default.htm#reference/r_access_the_command_line.htm).
The Command-Line Interface for the Digi device uses the *telnet* port, which is TCP port 23.
(The port number restrictions you were probably thinking of apply only if you do the server.)